# Center both the square in my animation and the circle over my image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using a static HTML page to serve as a loading page while the backend downloads a pass from passbook. On this static HTML page I have an animation that uses `morph` to transform between a circle and a square, which is centered on my logo. The trouble is, when this animation runs (currently iPhone-only, I will resize it later for different iOS screen resolutions) it is only centered over the image while it is a circle and not a square. See [this tweet](https://twitter.com/rxcs/status/470817251982327808) for some images of this behavior.

I have the script currently loaded onto reagentx.net/cards/test.html, and the code is [here](http://pastebin.com/XuSGZrVQ). Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Edit: Here are two jsfiddle pages. One for the current code (remember, iPhone only at the moment) jsfiddle.net/KFa4D/, and one for the circle itself jsfiddle.net/Grz7q/. Apologies!

Comment: Create a JSFiddle because the link you attached has several PHP errors

Comment: I've appended the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- An outer div ("spinner_outer_wrap") which has a width of 100% to cover the width of the page
- A wrap for the spinner ("spinner_wrap") which will have a fixed width and which should be centered using "margin:0 auto"
- Inside the spinner's wrap, the image takes the full width using "width:100%" and it has a "position:absolute" and a "z-index:1" to be positioned behind the spinner
- The spinner has a "z-index:2" to be positioned in front of the image

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes morph {
    0% {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        width: 440px;
        height: 440px;
    }

    25% {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        width: 440px;
        height: 440px;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        width: 440px;
        height: 440px;
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        width: 440px;
        height: 440px;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        width: 440px;
        height: 440px;
    }
}
.spinner_outer_wrap {
    width:100%;
}
.spinner_wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.spinner_wrap img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
}
.spinner {
            position:relative;
            top:0;
            left:0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:2;
    border: 7px solid #1abc9c;
    -webkit-animation-name: morph;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="spinner_outer_wrap">
    <div class="spinner_wrap">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
        <img src="http://reagentx.net/o/biglogo2.png" alt="" />
    </div>
<center><font size="150" color="#1abc9c">If you see this for more than a few seconds and no pass downloads, try and open in a separate browser like Safari or Chrome. Thanks!</font></center>
</div>
```

I've updated the JSFiddle. You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KFa4D/2/